# Getting tab index in nsIWebProgressListener:: onStateChange in C++

Tags: c++, firefox-addon

I am developing Firefox extension in C++
I want to get the tab index of the tab window for which I have got STATE_STOP for STATE_IS_NETWORK.
i.e. I want to find the tab index associated with the request.

How do i get it?

Please help me !!!

Thanks in advance,
Vaibhav.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is available at:
http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.tech.dom/browse_thread/thread/52ff471516662056#